# Install Ruby support for VIM on Mac OS X

Tags: ruby, macos, vim, autocomplete, osx-snow-leopard

Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) has VIM pre-installed (version 7.2), which is great.

It also has Ruby pre-installed (version 1.8.7) which is great too.

However, I want Ruby autocompletion in VIM. Looking up the VIM version (vim --version) shows -ruby (i.e. ruby support isn't enabled).

How to enable ruby for my VIM installation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While it's possible to build and install your own Vim to replace the pre-installed version, I don't recommend it. It's far easier to just use MacVim instead:

http://code.google.com/p/macvim/

MacVim is a very Mac-friendly version of Vim, and it's got Ruby support already built in. It can be used as both a GUI and Terminal application. (Check out `:help macvim-start` from within MacVim for details.)

Comment: This is the way to go on a mac. If you use the Homebrew package manager (http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/), compiling and installing is a breeze: `brew install macvim`.

Comment: and then if you need the command line version of vim with ruby support, use the one provided by MacVim -- /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim

Comment: Thanks, @jobano! Added that as an alias for vim. Works great for Command-T plugin.

Comment: @jobano this is the max. I like macvim, but vim from terminal even more!

Answer (score 2):

+1 for MacVim - I also use it and love it.

But if you want a fresh vim compiled with ruby support, you can build one from scratch on OSX by following this article:

http://brilliantcorners.org/2011/02/building-vim-on-osx-snow-leopard/

Only took me about 5 minutes to do...